# How to make text of nested lis cascade

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-lists

How can I make the `background color` to spread all over the line without `width:100%`

```html
<ul>
    <li style="background-color:#33FF33">11
        <ul>
            <li style="background-color:#CC3333">22
                <ul>
                    <li style="background-color:#336633">33 </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This is what I'm trying to achieve

[image]

Comment: Can you be a little bit more specific about what you are trying to do ?

Comment: Your html is wrong because `ul` can't be direct child of `ul`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking

Comment: @Mohammad don't know what code you are looking at, all the `ul`s are nested in `li`s

Comment: @Mohammad I don't see ul as child of ul in the OP's example.

Comment: @Relisora  This is OP's example <ul><li><ul><li></li></ul></li></ul> so ul is not the direct child of ul

Comment: @Tympaaz yeah my bad, saw it right after posting my comment

Comment: I added an Image of the I'm trying to achieve. Thanks

Comment: @user186585 Is it position to wrap `li` text by element?

Comment: @user186585 I updated my answer; is that how you want it? Your screenshot doesn't make it clear if you want the list items to have a specific width or not.

Comment: @Mohammad I thinks so (As long as we keep the overall canonical consept)

Comment: @MrLister Every chind should have maring from his father.

Comment: Are you waiting for new answer or @MrLister answer is your purpose?

Comment: @Mohammad still looking ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS `text-indent` property to making indentation in element text. But if you don't want to use it, you can use jquery [`.wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) to wrapping `div` around text of `li` and set `margin-left` for `div`.

```js
$("li").each(function(i){
    $(this).contents().eq(0).wrap("<div/>");
    $(this).find("div").css("margin-left", i * 40);  
});
```

```css
ul {
    padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li style="background-color:#33FF33">11
        <ul>
            <li style="background-color:#CC3333">22
                <ul>
                    <li style="background-color:#336633">33 </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by using `text-indent`.
Caveat: text-indents don't inherit nicely, so you will have to add different text-indents for each level of nested list items.

```css
ul, li {padding-left:0; margin-left:0; list-style: none}
li li {text-indent:2.5em}
li li li {text-indent:5em}
li li li li {text-indent:7.5em} /* and so on, how many levels you need */
```

```html
<ul>
    <li style="background-color:#33FF33">11
        <ul>
            <li style="background-color:#CC3333">22
                <ul>
                    <li style="background-color:#336633">33 </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```